# how to manipulate text to make it JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, text, filtering

Noob question;

Please help me with this.. I'm just a beginner and I'm finding it hard to do the following:

I want to manipulate this text using Javascript to make it look differently:

```
"5555 55:55: John: New York
 6666 66:66: Jack: Los Angeles"
```

After the manipulation I want it to be:

```
[{ name:"John", address:"New York", number:"5555 55:55"},{ name:"Jack", address:"Los Angeles", number:"6666 66:66"}]
```

So I really want to know how to tell Javascript that here is a new line, that means a new value.. here is a xxxx: and that's a name.. and here is a xxxx:(space) and after that is the address..

I don't know if that's possible but your help is really really appreciated. Thank you in advanced

**UPDATE**

text is:

```
var text = "5555 55:55: John: New York \n 6666 66:66: Jack: Los \n Angeles 7777 77:77: Smith: South Park: 3321"
```

my code so far:

```
var result = text.match(/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d: [a-zA-Z]+: /g)
                .map(function (x) {
                    x = x.split(': ');
                    return {
                        number: x[0],
                        name: x[1],
                        address: x[2]
                    };
                });
```

But I'm getting just the word "Los" because the regEx is wrong and the split at ': ' isn't working proberly because the Address has this sometimes.

Comment: Multiline strings are illegal in JavaScript, but if there's a reason I'm missing you could `split("\n")` (split on new line), loop over, and again `.split(":")` to further split into each object value.

Comment: Incidentally, this is not "JSON" -- it's a Javascript object.  JSON is the string representation of a Javascript value.

Comment: Unfortunately the text I'm working with is already multiline

Comment: What do you mean "already multiline"?  If the text is to be written out in Javascript, you cannot put literal newlines in it; you must write `\n`.  If it is in a file, and you are reading it with AJAX or some Node library, then there is not that problem.

Comment: The text comes from a file, yes.

Answer (score 6):

The following works on Firefox:

```
"5555 55:55: John: New York\n 6666 66:66: Jack: Los Angeles"
 .split('\n')
 .map(function(x) {
  x = x.split(': ');
  return {
    number: x[0],
    name: x[1],
    address: x[2]
  };
});
```

Other versions lack `map` and you will have to compensate.

Comment: You can get _.map() across browsers with the javascript Lo Dash library.

Comment: @steel -- _most_ Javascript libraries offer `map`!

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked actually like the others say in IE. I'm getting the text from a file in a Windows Store app and this is why there's multilines. It would be really a  tremendous help the code could search for `5555 55:55: ` (nnnn nn:nn: ) and then split it because the address is sometimes broken into two lines and this destroys the result.